# Google Autocomplete multiple fragment how to separate it's listeners method?

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, listener

so im kinda still learning how to program in android.

I am using the google autocomplete fragment and i have added two fragment into one xml layout , one to represent start point and the other for an end point.

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/autocomplete_fragment_origin"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In my main activity is where i initialize the auto complete fragment

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps); // to call the screen layout you do this first
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map); // this is how you call a fragment
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this); // implements OnMapReadyCallback which has the method onMapReady()

        // Just initializing the other object on activity_maps
        btnFindPath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);
        etOrigin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
        etDestination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);

        // Set Button On Click Listener
        btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendRequest();
            }
        });

        //Auto complete
        // Retrieve the PlaceAutocompleteFragment.
         autocompleteFragmentOrigin = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment_origin);
        autocompleteFragmentOrigin.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);

         autocompleteFragmentDestination = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment_destination);
        autocompleteFragmentDestination.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(this);

    }
```

And on the outside i had it's override listener method,

```
@Override
public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Place Selected: " + place.getName());
}
@Override
public void onError(Status status) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onError: Status = " + status.toString());

    Toast.makeText(this, "Place selection failed: " + status.getStatusMessage(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

So now i want to get the fragment's text which was selected , so i figured i could use the place parameter which is obtained through onPlaceSelected. However, how do i separate the listeners methods? Since i believe both of the fragment is currently sharing the same method now.

Answer (score 1):

You can set different listeners for autocompleteFragmentOrigin and  autocompleteFragmentDestination.

```
autocompleteFragmentOrigin.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {

        }
    });

autocompleteFragmentDestination = (SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentById(R.id.autocomplete_fragment_destination);
autocompleteFragmentDestination.setOnPlaceSelectedListener((new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks ! will try this out and let you know .